# React onClick JSX returned from function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, jsx

I'm using the array map method below to iterate over an array of image URLs, and return some JSX with the img src.

Ideally, I'd like to bind click to each image so that I can get this (clicked) img src into Redux later.

The below, gives me an error:

> Cannot read property 'changeImg' of undefined

```
<div className="gallery-thumbs">
        { galleryImages.map(function(img, index){
        return <img
                key={ img } 
                className="thumb-product-img" src={ img }
                onClick={ this.changeImg.bind(this) } />;
      }) }
    </div>
```

However, when I move the `onClick` up a level it doesn't give me the error... the only problem is, the context of this is lost.

```
<div className="gallery-thumbs" onClick={ this.changeImg.bind(this) }>
        { galleryImages.map(function(img, index){
        return <img
                key={ img }
                className="thumb-product-img" src={ img } />;
      }) }
    </div>
```

tl:dr; how can I bind click to JSX returned outside of my render method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will probably work if you change:

```
 <div className="gallery-thumbs">
        { galleryImages.map((img, index) => { //arrow function
        return <img
                key={ img } 
                className="thumb-product-img" src={ img }
                onClick={ this.changeImg.bind(this) } />;
      }) }
    </div>
```

I assume you loose the context while iterating over the array with `map`. A simple change from `function` to `arrow` function will probably do the trick.

[Here](https://medium.com/@machnicki/handle-events-in-react-with-arrow-functions-ede88184bbb) you can read more about `arrow` functions and their use as event handlers and more.

Comment: Thanks - this has solved it.  Need to remember to use arrow functions!

Comment: @Myles From `this.changeImg.bind(this)` I assume you didn't already bind those functions to your component: So whenever you define a function in your component you can define them like: `myFunction = () => {...}` to bind them to your component or you bind them once in your `constructor`: `this.changeImg= changeImg.bind(this);` you are then able to call `this.changeImg()` without binding it every time. If you ask me, `arrow` functions are way smoother though :)

Answer (score 1):

It means the lexical context `this` is `undefined`. It's the case when you use it inside a function call in strict mode ( which is the default mode for es modules).

what you could do is, inside the `render` method of your component class :

```
<div className="gallery-thumbs">
    { galleryImages.map((img, index) => {
    return <img
            key={ img } 
            className="thumb-product-img" src={ img }
            onClick={ e => this.changeImg(e) } />;
  }) }
</div>
```

The arrow function syntax creates a new function which does not have a lexical context, which means that invoking `this` in its body will reference the parent lexical context, in your case your component.

Because what you want is clearly identified : the src attribute of the image, you could, as an optimization, not create a new handler but instead create a generic one.

```
const handle = e => this.changeImg(e.currentTarget.src);
<div className="gallery-thumbs">
    { galleryImages.map((img, index) => {
    return <img
            key={ img } 
            className="thumb-product-img" src={ img }
            onClick={ handle } />;
  }) }
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this - haven't seen it done this way before.  I like your thinking, just passing over exactly what I need!

Answer (score 1):

you can use `arrow function` as @Nocebo said, you can also use map function like this :

```
<div className="gallery-thumbs">
    { 
      galleryImages.map(function(img, index){
       return <img
            key={ img } 
            className="thumb-product-img" src={ img }
            onClick={ this.changeImg.bind(this) } />;
      }, this) 
    }
</div>
```

`map` function take a second argument which will be the `Value` to use as this when executing `callback`